# Can the product of a positive definite and a symmetric matrix by skew-symmetric?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

I am interested in properties of the matrix product $AB$ where the matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is positive definite (i.e., $(Av,v)>0$ for all non-zero vectors $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$) and where matrix $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric (i.e., $(Bu,v)=(Bv,u)$ for all $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^n$).

I know that we can not expect positiveness or symmetry without additional assumptions but are we at least able to exlude skew-symmetry of the product (except for the trivial case $B=0$ of course)? I have tried to investigate this and expect it to be the case but I wasn't able to show it (or to find a counter-example).

Hence my question:

*Is it possible for the product $AB$ of a positive definite matrix $A$ and a symmetric matrix $B\neq0$ to be skew-symmetric?*

Note: I am specifically thinking about $n=3$ but have formulated the question for general dimension $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $B\ne0$, no, because $AB$ is similar to the real symmetric matrix $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$.

Comment: You mean $B$ instead of $B^{1/2}$ I think.

Comment: @OmranKouba Yes, of course. Thanks for the catch.